# Can Black crash through?

Tags: analysis

I wonder if White can defend below position:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "r4rk1/pppq2pp/2np1n2/2b1p1B1/8/2NP1N1b/PPP1BPP1/R2QR1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: is it white or black to move?

Comment: @Scounged: White moves, I stated it in the diagram...

Comment: ah, I totally missed that

Comment: After gxh3, this becomes pretty wild - I played it through a few times with a silicon friend of mine. It seems that black mounts an extremely strong attack and emerges at least with material advantage - obviously, I got crushed repeatedly trying to play this with white. Unfortunately, currently I do not have time to analyse this properly.. +1 for posting this cool position, though!

Comment: Stockfish is alternating between 1. gxh3 and some other move. Can you find the alternate first move without using an engine? (Answer forthcoming, but it amused me so I thought I'd post a comment...)

Comment: @GloriaVictis: Thank you for the upvote. It was a blitz game between an amateur and GM Jan Gustafsson, in one of his "banter blitz" sessions on chess24. I could not find out just how exactly black wins, neither did he ( but played it out because bishop sacrifice was fun for him ). That is why I decided to ask for help...

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Sadly, I have no idea where to start from. The position is so unclear for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [FEN "r4rk1/pppq2pp/2np1n2/2b1p1B1/8/2NP1N1b/PPP1BPP1/R2QR1K1 w - - 0 1"]

    1.Qd2 h6 2.Be3 Bxe3 3.fxe3 (3.Qxe3 Be6 4.Nd2 Rf7 5.Nde4 Ng4 6.Qg3 Raf8 7.Bf3 Nd4 8.Bxg4 Bxg4 9.Rac1 Be6 10.Ne2 Qa4 11.Nxd4 Qxd4 {-1.82. It took Stockfish 20 minutes to find `3...Be6`. It's preferred move until then was `3...Bg4`. Black is having a fine game.}) Be6 {So what we see here is that Black's attack is over. But the damage is done. He regroups with his extra pawn and better pawn structure.} 4.a3 Ne7 5.Ne4 {This is the best White has? To induce a doubled center pawn?} (5.e4 c5 6.Rf1 Rf7 7.Qe1 Raf8 8.Nd2 Ng6 9.Kh1 Nf4 10.Bf3 Nh7 11.Nd1 Ng5 12.Ne3 Qa4 13.b3 Qd4 14.Rd1 b5 15.Bg4 Bxg4 16.Nxg4 c4 17.dxc4 bxc4 18.bxc4 Qb2 {-1.78. White's position is passive and he gets picked apart.}) Nxe4 6.dxe4 Qc6 7.Bd3 Rf6 8.Rf1 Raf8 9.Qb4 R6f7 10.Nd2 b6 11.Rxf7 Rxf7 12.Bc4 Bxc4 13.Qxc4 Qxc4 14.Nxc4 Rf6 15.Nd2 Kf7 16.Rf1 Rxf1+ 17.Kxf1 Ng8 18.Kf2 Nf6 19.Ke2 Ke7 20.Kd3 Ke6 21.c3 a6 22.Kc4 b5+ 23.Kd3 { -1.58 }
```

```
    [FEN "r4rk1/pppq2pp/2np1n2/2b1p1B1/8/2NP1N1b/PPP1BPP1/R2QR1K1 w - - 0 1"]

    1.gxh3 Qxh3 2.Bf1 Bxf2+ 3.Kxf2 Ng4+ 4.Kg1 Qg3+ 5.Bg2 Nd4 6.Rf1 Nxf3+ 7.Rxf3 Rxf3 8.Qxf3 Qh2+ 9.Kf1 Rf8 10.Qxf8+ Kxf8 {White's King is flapping in the breeze; what White may be up in material he'll lose by being purely defensive with said pieces. White will be able to pick off pawns at will.} 11.Bd2 Qh4 12.Nd1 c6 13.Be1 Nh2+ 14.Ke2 Qh5+ 15.Kf2 Ng4+ 16.Kf1 d5 17.Bd2 Qh4 18.Be1 Nh2+ 19.Ke2 Qh5+ 20.Kf2 Ng4+ 21.Kf1 Kf7 22.a4 Qg5 23.Ke2 Nh2 24.Kf2 Qh4+ 25.Ke2 Qh5+ 26.Kf2 Qg5 27.Ne3 h5 28.a5 h4 29.a6 b6 30.Nf1 h3 31.Bxh3 Qf4+ 32.Kg1 Nf3+ 33.Kg2 Nd4 34.Bg3 Qf3+ 35.Kh2 Nxc2 36.Rc1 {-2.39 }
```

It's Kentucky Derby Day, and I live in Louisville, so celebrating is mandatory. More To Come.

As always, if you have any variations you want to see, let me know.